# Hadoop: Error while using wikipediaminer jar file in hadoop command

Tags: hadoop

I'm using [wikipediaminer](https://github.com/dnmilne/wikipediaminer) and Hadoop in my project.

When I run the following code in Linux terminal:

```
hadoop jar wikipedia-miner-hadoop.jar org.wikipedia.miner.extraction.DumpExtractor input/dump.xml input/languages.xml en input/en-sent.bin output
```

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/record/RecordInput
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.record.RecordInput
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

Can anyon

Comment: That code was built against Hadoop 1 libraries, and probably won't load on Hadoop 2... https://github.com/dnmilne/wikipediaminer/blob/master/wikipedia-miner-extract/pom.xml#L54

Comment: missing jar file might be the reason

Comment: @cricket_007 I will try use hadoop 1.2.0

Comment: @Sam you mean that "wikipedia-miner-hadoop.jar" is missing?

Comment: @TonyStarkus `org.apache.hadoop.record.RecordInput` is missing

Comment: check if the required jar files are present.

Comment: @Sam in directory /home/user_name/Programas/hadoop/share/doc/hadoop/api/org/apache/hadoop/record exist a file called "RecordInput.html"